# Can't run Xamarin.UITest on Test Cloud: Current JsonReader item is not an object

Tags: c#, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest, ios10.2

I have a trouble with running Xamarin.UITest tests in the Xamarin.TestCloud, although it passes on simulators and real iPads perfectly.

Application: I have the iOS app's source code(XCode project), which I linked to calabash via adding calabash.framework to the app(due to this [tutorial](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial:-Link-Calabash-in-Debug-config)) 
Although I found a lot of info that app needs `Xamarin.Calabash.Start()`,  I haven't added it anywhere because actually, I am not sure where and how I should put it in the XCode project. My modest opinion about it: this string is needed only for an application written in Xamarin Studio itself due to the simplification of linking the app to the calabash.framework.

To start tests in the BaseTest.class I added only:

```
app = ConfigureApp.
.iOS
.EnableLocalScreenshots()
.InstalledApp("com.ios.dev")
.StartApp();
```

After giving to Xamarin studio the .ipa file, it crashes with:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/bin/mono "/Users/pavlo.shtefanesku/Xamarin/fieldforcetest/packages/Xamarin.UITest.2.0.7/tools/test-cloud.exe" asubmit "/Users/pavlo.shtefanesku/Documents/appStore/MobileField.ipa" --async --fixture QLFieldForceiOSUITests.LoginTests.LoginForTheFirstTime --assembly-dir "/Users/pavlo.shtefanesku/Xamarin/fieldforcetest/QLFieldForceiOSUITests/bin/Debug"
Negotiating file upload to Xamarin Test Cloud.
Posting to https://testcloud.xamarin.com/ci/anonymous_uploads

Uploading Xamarin.UITest.dll ... Already uploaded.
Uploading nunit.framework.dll ... Already uploaded.

Uploading MobileField.ipa... 10%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 20%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 30%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 40%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 50%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 60%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 70%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 80%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 91%
Uploading MobileField.ipa... 100%

Uploading CsvHelper.dll... 41%
Uploading CsvHelper.dll... 83%
Uploading CsvHelper.dll... 100%
Uploading CsvHelper.dll... 100%

Uploading QLFieldForceiOSUITests.dll... 98%
Uploading QLFieldForceiOSUITests.dll... 100%
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Integer. Path '', line 1, position 3.
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

in advance, I don't use any JSON objects or whatever implicitly at least.

The additional packages used in the test project is only CsvHelper,

Xamarin version: 6.2(build 1821)
NUnit: 2.6.4
Xamarin.UITest: 2.0.7
Mac OS: 10.12.3 (16D32)

Please help with this issue.

Comment: I've seen this symptom before if the IPA was packaged incorrectly, though I don't know if that's the only way to encounter this error.

Can you reproduce this in a "dummy" app (e.g. so you don't have to share your actual app), and then share that IPA as a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already resolved this issue. As @Kent.Green mentioned it was the problem with the .ipa file of the app, I've just forgotten to put the .app in the "Payload" folder before zipping it. 
p.s. Thanks to Xamarin Test cloud support, Kent helped me as a Pro:)